# tmux malloc() fault on sorting mailbox

Tags: mutt

I am getting a lot of these errors from `mutt`:

```
Sorting mailbox...*** glibc detected *** mutt: malloc(): smallbin double linked list corrupted: 0x08f12d20 ***
```

No particular condition triggers the fault yet no state is immune from it as a haven (message previews, index browsing, etc...).

Any idea as to how to go about troubleshooting this? I am sure the C hackers out there will know exactly what to do with this...

`strace`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's obviously a bug, fire a [bug report here](http://dev.mutt.org/trac/), fix it yourself could be a massive task.

Comment: A bug indeed. Thanks a lot for finding exactly the right bug filing site for me!